# How to get source maps to work with tsc and tsc-alias in TypeScript with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

My source maps are being generated but they are not accurate. They say what file and function/method they are in, but the line number and column are off. Any idea if it's [`tsc-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) causing this, and if so, how to fix?

My build command is:

```
tsc && tsc-alias
```

My watch command is:

```
concurrently --kill-others "tsc -w" "tsc-alias -w"
```

My project is fairly large so hard to isolate to a small example.

My aliases are defined in `tsconfig.json` like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": "make",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": "./make",
    "paths": {
      "~": ["."]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["make"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And I use it in a circular fashion like:

```
import { api } from '~'
```

But the line numbers are off.